# Error "object 'int' not iterable" in custom "seq" function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a `seq` function which would create a list from `from` to `to`, but I get the error "object 'int' not iterable". What's wrong?

```
def seq (ffrom, to, by=1):
    x = ffrom
    l = list(x)
    #extending list
    while x < to:
        l.append(x+1)
        x = x + 1
    #Returning value
    tuple(l)
    print(l)
```

I get the error that the the list `xline` isn't iterable.

Comment: Please show how you call the function. The error suggests your `ffrom` is a number. Numbers are not iterable

Comment: Also, it seems you just want `return list(range(ffrom, to, step=by))`

Comment: What do you expect `list(x)` to do, if `x = ffrom` and `ffrom` is a number?

Comment: BTW, you aren't actually returning any value at all.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow's scope is limited to _practical_, answerable questions. Building a less-efficient implementation of something that already exists in the Python standard library is impractical by nature.

Comment: @OneCricketeer: `return list(range(ffrom, to, by))` (no `step=`); `range` doesn't accept arguments by keyword, only positionally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notation `list(x)` tries to build a list with all elements of `x`, but as the error states : `int isn't iterable`

What you want is

```
l = [x]
```

---

```
def seq(ffrom, to, by=1):
    x = ffrom
    l = [x]
    while x < to:
        x += by
        l.append(x)
    print(l)


seq(5, 8)
print(list(range(5, 9)))
```

Answer (score 0):

`l = list(x)` needs to be `l = [x]` to make a list of one item with `x` in it:

```
def seq(ffrom, to, by=1):
    x = ffrom
    l = [ffrom]

    #extending list
    while x < to:
        x = x + 1
        l.append(x)
    
    return l
```